# Unable to upload images on laravel app to hostgator hosting

Tags: php, laravel

I've been searching all around the net to try to fix this problem. Changed the code in my controllersfolder multiple times and still no solution. I changed the permissions of my img folder and products folder to 777 and still no success.

This is the structure of my folders on my FTP cyberduck:

```
-->app_base/ ( Has Everything from the base laravel folder EXCEPT the /public/ folder)
-->[some other folders...]
-->public_html/ 
    -->daveswebapp.us/ (name of my website. Has all the content of my base public/folder)
       -->img
         -->products
             [empty folder]
```

This is the error I receive each time I try to upload new product images in my admin panel:

```
Intervention \ Image \ Exception \ NotWritableException 
Can't write image data to path         (/home2/ecuanaso/app_base/bootstrap/img/products/1417822656.jpg)
```

PRODUCTS CONTROLLER CODE:

```
<?php

class ProductsController extends BaseController {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on'=>'post'));
    $this->beforeFilter('admin');
}

public function getIndex() {
    $categories = array();

    foreach(Category::all() as $category) {
        $categories[$category->id] = $category->name;
    }

    return View::make('products.index')
        ->with('products', Product::all())
        ->with('categories', $categories);
}

public function postCreate() {
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Product::$rules);

    if ($validator->passes()) {
        $product = new Product;
        $product->category_id = Input::get('category_id');
        $product->title = Input::get('title');
        $product->description = Input::get('description');
        $product->price = Input::get('price');

        $image = Input::file('image');
        $filename  = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = public_path('img/products/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(468, 249)->save($path);
        $product->image = 'img/products/'.$filename;
        $product->save();

        return Redirect::to('admin/products/index')
            ->with('message', 'Product Created');
    }

    return Redirect::to('admin/products/index')
        ->with('message', 'Something went wrong')
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}

public function postDestroy() {
    $product = Product::find(Input::get('id'));

    if ($product) {
        File::delete('public/'.$product->image);
        $product->delete();
        return Redirect::to('admin/products/index')
            ->with('message', 'Product Deleted');
    }

    return Redirect::to('admin/products/index')
        ->with('message', 'Something went wrong, please try again');
}

public function postToggleAvailability() {
    $product = Product::find(Input::get('id'));

    if ($product) {
        $product->availability = Input::get('availability');
        $product->save();
        return Redirect::to('admin/products/index')->with('message', 'Product Updated');
    }

    return Redirect::to('admin/products/index')->with('message', 'Invalid Product');
}
```

}

Comment: could be server settings.  Look in your php.ini

Comment: Like what? Could you be more specific

Comment: Make your code simple by just seeing where they are uploading to begin with.  `Input::file('photo')->getRealPath();`  just to see if it's even uploading.

Comment: If your code was working on your machine changes are it's just server settings.

Comment: I changed $image = Input::file('image'); to Input::file('photo')->getRealPath(); and I received this error now: Call to a member function getRealPath() on a non-object

Comment: `Input::file('image')->getRealPath();` just replace the word photo with image (your field name).

Comment: I received this error message now:

Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on a non-object

Comment: Check the name of your field and put it there in the file()

Comment: Your advice for some reason just gave me more errors. I went back and changed the code to what I had it in my localhost. It still doesn't work however now I can go about trying to find out why it works on my local host but not in my production host.

Comment: when files get uploaded they are stored in a temporary folder defined in PHP.ini (the development configuration file) if your php.ini is not referencing a location readable by your code...your code won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I created a php.ini file in my shared server. But i'm stumped on what to change to allow my code to be readable.

Comment: the php.ini file should already be in your server (no need to create one).  [PHP.ini in cPanel](https://phpmatters.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/php.ini-config.jpg)  What is your environment?  cpanel or plesk?

Comment: "If you're on a shared hosting environment you won't have access to the php.ini to make these changes, if you need access, a virtual private server (VPS) or a dedicated server may be a better option if you're confident in managing it yourself."

Comment: You can get your current working directory using [_DIR_ constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) you just need to edit your php / laravel script to upload to a location it can see

Answer (score 0):

Images should go into public folder and not in app directory in your code you are trying to move the image into app directoy but defining directory address with public_path the following code uploads an image into your public/uploads folder which is then accessible via visiting yourdomain.com/img.jpg

```
//create two empty variables outside of conditional statement because we gonna access them later on 
    $filename = "";
    $extension = "";
//check if you get a file from input, assuming that the input box is named photo
    if (Input::hasFile('photo'))
    {
//create an array with allowed extensions
        $allowedext = array("png","jpg","jpeg","gif");
/get the file uploaded by user
        $photo = Input::file('photo');
//set the destination path assuming that you have chmod 777 the upoads folder under public directory
        $destinationPath = public_path().'/uploads';
//generate a random filename 
        $filename = str_random(12);
//get the extension of file uploaded by user
        $extension = $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
//validate if the uploaded file extension is allowed by us in the $allowedext array
        if(in_array($extension, $allowedext ))
        {
//everything turns to be true move the file to the destination folder
            $upload_success = Input::file('photo')->move($destinationPath, $filename.'.'.$extension);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if a a solution goes here but I figured it out after days of seaching.

I was saving the file into the wrong directory. took out the public from ->save method

I changed

```
Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(468, 249)->save('public/img/products/'.$filename);
```

to:

```
Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(468, 249)->save('img/products/'.$filename);
```